# Mysqli query does submits the form

Tags: php, mysql

Kindly suggest if the below code is right for updating in MYSQL. When i try to submit by form the program dies.

This is my code

```
<?php
include('sdg_connect.php');

$securedmember=$_POST['securedmember'];
$modifiedtime=$_POST['modifiedtime'];
$url=$_POST['url'];
$member_id=$_GET['member_id'];
$member_name=$_POST['member_name'];
$member_mob=$_POST['member_mob'];
$member_emailid=$_POST['member_emailid'];
$member_age=$_POST['member_age'];
$member_weight=$_POST['member_weight'];
$member_sex=$_POST['member_sex'];
$member_address1=$_POST['member_address1'];
$member_address2=$_POST['member_address2'];
$member_occupation=$_POST['member_occupation'];
$member_joindate=$_POST['member_joindate'];
$member_gymplan=$_POST['member_gymplan'];
$member_feespaid=$_POST['member_feespaid'];
$member_reference=$_POST['member_reference'];
$sdg_cheque_no=$_POST['sdg_cheque_no'];
$member_feesdue=$_POST['member_feesdue'];
$sdg_trainer=$_POST['sdg_trainer'];
$sdg_time=$_POST['sdg_time'];
$sdg_expire_date=$_POST['sdg_expire_date'];
if (isset($_POST['member_info_save']))  {
    $sdg_member_query = "UPDATE sdg_members SET member_name='$member_name', member_mob='$member_mob', member_emailid='$member_emailid', member_age='$member_age', member_weight='$member_weight', member_sex='$member_sex', member_address1='$member_address1', member_address2='$member_address2', member_occupation='$member_occupation', member_joindate='$member_joindate', member_gymplan='$member_gymplan', member_feespaid='$member_feespaid', member_reference='$member_reference', sdg_cheque_no='$sdg_cheque_no', member_feesdue='$member_feesdue', sdg_trainer='$sdg_trainer', sdg_time='$sdg_time', sdg_expire_date='$sdg_expire_date', modifiedtime='$modifiedtime' WHERE member_id='$member_id'";


        mysqli_query($conn, $sdg_member_query) or die('Error occured while saving members data <a href='.$url.'>Go Back</a>');

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['msg']="<div class=\"col-md-10\" style=\"padding: 5px 0px;font-size: 12px;border-radius: 5px;background: #EEEEEE;position: fixed;bottom: 75px;text-align: center;left: 8%;box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(179, 176, 176, 0.67);\">Member details has been successfully update</div>";
         header('location:'.$url.'');

    }
    else    {
        header('location:'.$url.'');
    }
?>
```

Please let me know if above code is proper

Comment: So much wrong with this. SQL Injection prone, use of deprecated mysqli functions, and why are you storing the status result in the SESSION? Just append a status "code" to the url string and test for it on that page for proper output to user. Also session-start() has to be the very first line after your opening <?php tag.

Comment: echo the completed sql statement to screen and inspect it closely - copy completed statement and try to run it in your gui application

Comment: some pointers:- 1. `session_start();` must be on top of the page after `<?php`. 2 change `mysqli_query($conn, $sdg_member_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` so that you will come to know if any query error occur. 3.`error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` put this code just after `session_start();`on top of your page
`

Comment: *...i try to submit by form the program dies.*, what do you mean by that? For the debugging purpose add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the data types for each column in table. For columns that are of integer type you don't need to use the ' (single quotation mark). For example if the member_id field is integer then you side write the code as

```
WHERE member_id=$member_id
```

without the ' sign.

Do this for all the variables that are integers.

Comment: some pointers:- 1. `session_start();` must be on top of the page after `<?php`. 2 change `mysqli_query($conn, $sdg_member_query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` so that you will come to know if any query error occur. 3.`error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` put this code just after `session_start();`on top of your page
`

Comment: You have to check whether it is an integer or not. Then you must decide whether to remove ' or not. and what is the error?

Comment: A-2-A your answer did helped, Thank you